# Batch command to add some information into multiple files in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have been searching for an answer for days but no success at all as a very newbie on batch commands.

My folder contains several text files. I would like to add several lines which all are coming from another text file. Since text files do not follow a pattern, I'll use line numbers. For instance,

My main input text file includes those lines respectively.

```
This is explanation.
This one is another line.
That is a short content.
```

I'd like to add these lines above in to the all text files in my folder, based on certain lines (for instance, 3,7,and 9, this may be changed later)
This is the one of those files:

```
My file contains
Too many lines
This is a line
This one is another line
It goes on
Another sample
Another line
One more
Another more
```

After adding 3,7,9 respectively from the main input file

```
My file contains
Too many lines
This is explanation. <---- 3 goes here without deleting any line
This is a line
This one is another line
It goes on
Another sample
This one is another line. <---- 7 goes here
Another line
One more
That is a short content. <---- 9 goes here
Another more
```

I tried to have it done with Regex and Macro Record. It may be okay with Notepad++ Macro Records. However, I'd like to have it done with a batch file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question really? Is it "How to achieve this with batch?" Few people are gonna write code for you... You have to try and/or ask specific questions, not "Write this code for me, thanks"

Comment: Google e.g "add to text file in for loop in batch", you should see some examples to set you of in the right direction. '

Comment: Hello @niCkcAMel thank you for informing me. I am aware of the situation. The problem is that I am not a coder. Despite this truth, I've been searching for an answer and trying to do it myself wondering whether I can handle or not. I have already found some similar samples through the web as well as on Stackoverflow, but none of them helps me.

Comment: Hehe yeah I get it, this forum is just not built on the type of request you are making. But still, somebody might help you before this question gets closed as "too broad". Good luck

Comment: Thank you. I will keep my hopes. We'll see if somebody helps me over this subject. As I said, I am not a coder, nor a professional. All I need is to get a little help.

Comment: You have been given enough examples in your previous questions to at least make an attempt at coding this.  I would go as far to say that you should be able to come real close to accomplishing this task yourself based on your previous questions.

Comment: I am sorry, Squashman. I'll then follow a Macro solution instead of batch. It's a little bit harder to learn for someone who is 40 years.

Comment: Life itself is a lifelong learning process. My Mother went back to school when she was 50 to get a Masters degree. She got her PhD at 60. So there is no excuse for learning anything is what I am trying to convey.

Comment: You are right, Squashman. I gonna take this into consideration. I leave the question here anyway while searching a solution; If I can adapt the code myself, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually ignore questions that don't show any effort from the OP to write code. However, I do an exception in this case because the solution involve a not so simple concept (file merge).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "lines=3 7 9"

rem Initialize first line number to search
for /F "tokens=1*" %%i in ("%lines%") do (
   set "line=%%i"
   set "lines=%%j"
)

rem Redirect the input to *read* lines via SET /P command from input.txt file
< input.txt (

   rem Process the text file. Use FINDSTR /N command to numerate the lines in %%a
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" test.txt') do (

      if "%%a" equ "!line!" (

         rem Read next line from input.txt and output it
         set /P "nextLine="
         echo !nextLine!

         rem Get the next line number to search
         for /F "tokens=1*" %%i in ("!lines!") do (
            set "line=%%i"
            set "lines=%%j"
         )

      )

      rem Output the original line
      echo %%b
   )
)
```

**test.txt:**

```
My file contains
Too many lines
This is a line
This one is another line
It goes on
Another sample
Another line
One more
Another more
```

**input.txt:**

```
This is explanation.
This one is another line.
That is a short content.
```

The output:

```
My file contains
Too many lines
This is explanation.
This is a line
This one is another line
It goes on
Another sample
This one is another line.
Another line
One more
That is a short content.
Another more
```

This solution just process one text file so you need to extend the method in order to process several files. Note that you must repeat *the whole process* with each individual text file...

Comment: Dear @Aacini, I will never forget your help. Thank you very much. I have to acknowledge other friends who are involved in the subject, niCk cAMel and Squashman. Squashman is absolutely right; I should have done much more effort. Searching a code is not even a single part of my work, in fact, I didn't make any coding work during my life, but I promise... regardless of business work, I will struggle to learn batch coding in my free time. Thank you much again.

Comment: Hello @Aacini I have just tried your batch file. input.txt and test.txt are in the same folder (Documents) with batch file. After running the batch, nothing seemed to have changed. test.txt content as an output is the same. Might I have missed a point?

Comment: Hi @Aacini I tried to do solve the issue myself; either full path and filename itself in quotation for input.txt but still no luck to work. Is it related to "%lines&" ?